# How can i get a value from a string with an alternating name?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var currentCity = db.City.Find(player.Location);

switch (TravelTo) {
    case 1:
        costs = currentCity.TravelCost.City1;
        break;
    case 2:
        costs = currentCity.TravelCost.City2;
        break;
    case 3:
        costs = currentCity.TravelCost.City3;
        break;
    case 4:
        costs = currentCity.TravelCost.City4;
        break;
    case 5:
        costs = currentCity.TravelCost.City5;
        break;
}
```

Is there a better way to get the cost value? Is there a way i can change the name of the string i want to call? So i could create something like

```
costs = currentCity.TravelCost.City[TravelTo]
```

Or something like that? I feel i wrote an unnecessary switch statement but my knowledge of C# is not good enough to come up with an alternative.

Thanks,

Comment: If `City` was an array you could.

Comment: Actually it depends how TravelCost class is implemented. An array? A list? A Dictionary? A bunch of properties? For first cases you can expose an indexer (for example), and in the last case you (may) use reflection. Probably the point is that an integer isn't a very good idea to identify a city. You have objects so you should use relations within them.

Comment: I insist on one single point: make TravelTo a reference to an object of type City. Change (at least) TravelCost to be a dictionary (or a list of tuples) of <City,Decimal>

Comment: If you post the code for TravelCost class then we could give refactoring suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a better way given you have those `City1..n` column and property names. But you could at least put this switch statement within the `TravelCost` entity. I.e. you could have a method `public int TravelCost.GetCostByCity(int city)` which held the nasty switch statement.

Comment: I went for this approach, still not my favorite solution but it's better than what i had.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to c# myself, and I am unsure exactly what data types each of these are. But the code itself looks fine. I take it TravelCost is an enum ? If not, it is a great idea to make it such. You can also use a Dictionary to store and manipulate data. But to me this looks good enough

Comment: Dictionary<string, myDataValueType>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `hashtable`.

Try this:

```
Hashtable distancesFromCityTo = new Hashtable();    
distancesFromCityTo.Add("City1", 1000);
distancesFromCityTo.Add("City2", 450);

int cost1 = (int)distancesFromCityTo["City1"];
int cost2 = (int)distancesFromCityTo["City2"];
```